# looping redirect login security.yml

Tags: symfony

someone could help me solve this problem in the login redirection?
the browser says that the page has made too many redirects

here i show file security.yml:

```
firewalls:
    frontend:
        pattern:  ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
            default_target_path: /index
            success_handler: authentication_handler
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /
            success_handler: authentication_handler
        security: true
        remember_me:
            key:      sitio123
            lifetime: 604800        # 7 * 24 * 3600 = 604.800 = 1 semana
        access_denied_handler: accessdenied_handler

access_control:
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_U }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_A }
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/pruebita, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/prueba, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/comprobarmail, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/nuevacontrasena, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }


providers:
    chain_provider:
        providers: [in_memory, user_db]
    in_memory:
        users:
            foo: { password: test, roles: 'ROLE_A' }
            foo1: { password: test1, roles: 'ROLE_U' }
    user_db:
        entity: { class: mio\mioBundle\Entity\Empleado, property: username }

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_A:       ROLE_U

encoders:
    mio\mioBundle\Entity\Empleado: { algorithm: sha1 }
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
```

thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the anonymous access control items before the secured items:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/pruebita, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/prueba, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/comprobarmail, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/nuevacontrasena, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_U }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_A }
```

Comment: the problem is that now in the login screen and I caught the css or javascript

Comment: You have to place css and javascript in a directory which does not require autentification

Comment: the css if it works but the javascript does not work just talk to the login screen. within the application everything works fine.

Comment: the login template extends the base template in the base template i have: <script id="scriptInit" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
          alert("holita");

Comment: I repeat: You have to place css and javascript in a directory which does not require autentification. For example, place javscripts in a 'js' directory and then add - { path: ^/js, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

Comment: I have solved the problem, but I do not understand why take the css and javascript not in the login form.thanks